# Docker GitLab image that update itself

Tags: docker, gitlab

Does everyone know a docker gitlab image that update itself when new release comes out ?

I fix the version for now because I haven't try the automatique update using the :latest tagged image.

I have tested sameersbn/gitlab and gitlab/gitlab-ce image.

Does anyone has any recommendation for updating safely ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

**Upgrading to latest Gitlab**

By using docker the upgrade process of gitlab becomes very simple. We update the image in our `docker-compose.yml` to use `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

So now whenever we pull the images, it would always pull the latest version.

**upgrade_gitlab.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pull the latest image
docker-compose pull | grep -q "Image is up to date"

IMAGE_UPDATED=$?

if [ $IMAGE_UPDATED -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "New image found for Gitlab"

    echo "Backing up old Gitlab"
    docker-compose exec gitlab gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create

    # Update docker
    docker-compose up -d

    # Check logs for any issues
    docker-compose logs -f
else
  echo "No update found for Gitlab"
fi
```

Now you can schedule this script or execute it using jenkins. Whatever node you like

PS: Taken from my article http://tarunlalwani.com/post/migrating-gitlab-6-mysql-to-latest-gitlab/